# Can I reduce this Perl regex's atom's repetiton?

Tags: regex

```
^([rat])(?!\g1)([rat])(?!(\g2|\g1))[rat]$
```

If possible, I want to get rid of the repetition of `[rat]` in my regex. May be substitute it for something like `\c` or so.

Comment: Probably [`^(?!.*(.).*\1)[rat]{3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/pJFqCF/1), if all you need is to match a string consisting of non-repeating `r`, `a`, `t` chars.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is happening inside `(?! ...)`?

Comment: It fails the match if there is a repeating char inside the string. Does it work as you expect?

Comment: It works as expected but can you please elaborate it in answer? Since I am new to assertions.

Comment: See an answer below. It is the same pattern, in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching unique characters from character class. Simply saying input string should not contain a second occurrence of defined characters. Just check if the opposite happens:

```
([rat]).*\1
```

Or all in one go, validating if string follows `^[rat]{3}$` rule as well:

```
^(?!.*?(.).*\1)[rat]{3}$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/sWIyuE/1)

Breakdown:

- `^` Assert beginning of input string
- `(?!` Construct a negative lookahead

  - `.*?(.).*\1` Look for duplicate characters
- `)` End of negative lookahead
- `[rat]{3}` Match a 3 char long string including defined chars
- `$` End of input string